# Reset form objects to default attributes

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a textbox that I want to reset to it's initialized properties (font, color, text contents, etc).

Is there a method to call that resets it back to it's properties at initialization?

Comment: textbox where? HTML? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @trashr0x Windows Forms Application

Comment: Define what you mean by "initialization".  Many properties have a Reset**PropertyName** method that can be called to reset their values back to what they were when the control was created.   These methods are what allows you to Reset a property in the designer via the PropertyGrid.

Comment: You can use property binding to application settings and bind those properties to a setting file. Then when you need to reset those properties, you can simple reset setting class. For example take a look at [Save Settings in VB.Net or C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367370/reset-part-of-application-settings). You can perform binding in both designer and code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Control.Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property, it allows you to store or retrieve data on a control.

> Any type derived from the `Object` class can be assigned to this property. If the Tag property is set through the Windows Forms designer, only text can be assigned.

You could as such create, for example, your own `TextBoxMetadata` class containing properties like `BackColor`, `Text`, etc and saving that to the `.Tag` property of your `textBox`. You can then do something like:

```
var defaultTextboxData = new TextBoxMetadata();
defaultTextboxData.Text = "Default Text";
defaultTextboxData.BackColor = Color.Green;
// ...etc
myTextBox.Tag = defaultTextboxData;
```

Upon reset you can access the properties of your `TextBoxMetadata` instance  from `myTextBox.Tag` and use them to restore the textbox property values.