# How to reset all object Properties on winform to the initiate?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

I am creating a Winforms project in VS2022.

To some text boxes and buttons I set `enable = false`, etc..

The user can change it on some conditions, and I want to add a "logout" button that will restore the original properties I gave the objects.

Anyway to do it globally? Or do I really have to initiate each one?

Comment: There is not a method to "reset" them. Either set them in code or recreate the form.

Comment: ok, thx anyway.

Comment: You can bind properties of Controls to the Application Settings, if you're targeting .Net Framework. In that case, to reset the properties to default values, you can simply call the `Reset()` method. This simple procedure is described here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103)

Comment: Have been working for years with WinForms, never knew that @jimi

Comment: Another example, like what mentioned by Jimi, [Reset part of application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370440/3110834) It allows you to reset some or all properties based on property-binding to application settings.

Comment: If you are using .NET 5 or 6, then to bind properties to application settings you need to write a bit of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70553881/3110834).